# Is there anyway to reverse an ether transaction on binance or etherscan?

Tags: blockchain, ether

Help please! I sent all my ether to a fraud website about an hour ago. I tried contacting the email that was on website, but it said it was invalid.I need to cancel it ASAP.

Comment: No, you cannot reverse a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

No. Ethereum transactions are final and cannot be undone. Assuming an actual transaction was made and was already mined into a block, nothing can now undo it, so you're at the mercy of whoever controls the account the ether was sent to.

Just to confirm, do you have a transaction hash and you see that transaction on etherscan.io as having completed successfully? If so, then I'm afraid there's nothing you can do.